# How can I use FormApp.create in a google sheet custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, custom-function

I want to create a custom function in google sheet so that it can take the data of that sheet as the input of the function. And the output will be the URL of a form created. I have the google app script that can create a form and generate the URL.

However, it gives me the following error when I try to implement the function:

```
Exception: You do not have permission to call FormApp.create. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms
```

I have looked into other posts. But it just doesn't work.

Comment: While the above link is about "openById", the same answer applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services):

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can only call services that do not have access to personal data[.]

`FormApp.create` would manipulate your personal data by creating something in your Drive, which would violate the rules of using Apps Script services in a custom function.